# Python Tkinter; Creating multiple labels without declaring each one individually. Is there a way to put this in a for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

To be more specific, I need to create 45 different labels that I can control the bg color of individually based on the user input. The project is a lottery, and each correct number the user gets needs to change it's bg color.

```
lbl_lotoNumberTip1 = Label(lotto, text="1", bg='green')
lbl_lotoNumberTip2 = Label(lotto, text="2", bg='green')
lbl_lotoNumberTip3 = Label(lotto, text="3", bg='green')
lbl_lotoNumberTip4 = Label(lotto, text="4", bg='green')
lbl_lotoNumberTip5 = Label(lotto, text="5", bg='green')
```

Is there a much shorter way to write this like putting it in a for loop ?

Comment: Have you considered storing your labels in a list and creating them with a for loop? You will find plenty of examples on the Internet, e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317403/how-to-name-tkinter-entry-widgets-created-from-a-for-loop

Comment: What about grid, place and pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some few corrections to my code

```
labels = {} # Create a dictionary 
for i in range(45):
  labels[f'lbl_lotoNumberTip{i+1}'] = Label(lotto, text=f"i+1", bg='green')
```

The code above will create the labels to access the labels use.

```
labels[lbl_lotoNumberTip1] # where 1 there can be replaced with any number in the range
labels[lbl_lotoNumberTip2].text() # Example on how to access labels
```

Comment: It is better to update your original answer instead of new one except that the new one uses another solution.  BTW `text=f"i+1"` should be `text=f"{i+1}"` instead, or simply `text=i+1`.

Comment: Ok thanks I will next, am new here

Answer (score 0):

If you need 45 different labels then you can create a dictionary which will store the labels and loop 45 times to create you labels. See code below.

```
labels = {}
for i in range(45):
  labels[f'lbl_lotoNumberTip{i+1}'] = Label((lotto, text="1", bg='green')
```

The code above will create the labels to access the labels use.

```
labels[lbl_lotoNumberTip1] # where 1 there can be replaced with any number in the range
labels[lbl_lotoNumberTip2].text() # Example on how to access labels
```

Comment: Should `text="1"` be `text=i+1` instead?

Comment: Yes that's True it was an error thanks for the correction